# how can i add link in my project card component i use Link tag and anchor tag both but i cant add link in my project card component

Tags: typescript, next.js, framer-motion

i use link tag but unable to show the action of it in my UI as its not working please suggest so that it work properly

[image]

i expect that my link tag is work properly and i redirect to the specified page but unfortunately link tag is not working i also used anchor tag instead  of link but it also not working. so what can i do.

```
<Link href="https://github.com/Shivendra-11/swiggy" target="_blank">

        <ProjectCard 
          src="/Swiggy.png"
          title="Swiggy Clone"
          description="Made a clone of the swiggy website using react and tailwind css. used redux tools Hooks and context api for state management and Deep dive into JSX and other core  ."
        />
        </Link>
```

Comment: Quick tip, if you want to link to external URLs, you would typically use a regular anchor (<a>) tag. Link is used for routing.

Comment: In addition, please provide your code as text since it's easy to deal with instead of images.